# Python - Pandas Tricky sum of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a tricky question, I have a dataframe like this and I want to create 3 columns with conditional sums such as,

1. If the id = A then A = A1 and B and C = B1
2. If the id = B then B = B1 and A and C = A1

Example data:

```
id A1  B1   A   B   C
A   5   4   5   4   4
B   6   1   6   1   6
A   7   2   7   2   2
B   6   8   8   6   6
C   2   1   2   1   0
```

I´m trying to come with a general solution so I don´t need a lot of sum by axis.

Comment: Check your result for row 4, it should be `6 8 6`

Answer (score 3):

Your condition can be reduced to:

- if id == A, then column A = column A1, column C = column B1
- if id == B, then column B = column B1, column C = column A1

So, it transferred to pandas code as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5,4],[6,1],[7,2],[6,8],[2,1]], index=['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['A1', 'B1'])


df['A'] = df['A1']
df['B'] = df['B1']
df['C'] = (df.index == 'B')*df['A1'] +(df.index == 'A')*df['B1']
# or faster method from @user3483203 
# df['id'] = df.index
# df['C'] = np.select([df.id.eq('A'), df.id.eq('B')], [df.B1, df.A1], 0)

# >>> df
#    A1  B1  A  B  C
# A   5   4  5  4  4
# B   6   1  6  1  6
# A   7   2  7  2  2
# B   6   8  6  8  6
# C   2   1  2  1  0
```

Comment: To create `c`: `np.select([df.id.eq('A'), df.id.eq('B')], [df.B1, df.A1], 0)`, will be faster

Comment: You don't need to call `list()`, you can just have `(df.index == 'B') * df['A1']`. Where possible it's better to leave things as `Series`, to get the full benefit of pandas' fast vectorised operations.